# Crash at chkstk

Tags: c

I wrote a program in Linux that runs just fine. When I compile and run the code on Windows, it always crashes at the same spot with the top of the callstack being `chkstk()`. I tried it in both Code::Blocks and VS2013 and they crash at the same spot, except for Code::Blocks it's `chkstk_ms()` (assuming this is the MinGW version?).

Compiling with `-std=c11` in Linux and in Code::Blocks.

Here is the relevant code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>

#define LINE_SIZE 2097152

bool doUnescape = false;
int filesDehexed = 0;

void dehexFile(const char* filename);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int files = 0;
    char* filenameList[argc];

    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("Please pass in a filename.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if((argc == 2) && (strcmp("-u", argv[1]) == 0)) {
        printf("No filename was passed in.\n");
        return 0;
    } else if((argc == 2) && strcmp("-u", argv[1]) != 0) {
        filenameList[0] = argv[1];
        files = 1;
    }

    if(argc >= 3) {
        for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            if(strcmp("-u", argv[i]) == 0) {
                doUnescape = true;
            } else if(i > 0) { //SHOULD be a file name
                filenameList[j] = argv[i];
                j++;
                files++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Dehexifying %d file%s...\n", files, files <= 1 ? "" : "s");
    for(int i = 0; i < files; i++) {
        dehexFile(filenameList[i]);
    }
    printf("...%d file%s dehexed\n", filesDehexed, filesDehexed <= 1 ? "" : "s");

    return 0;
}

void dehexFile(const char* filename)
{
...
}
```

When debugging, both (Code::Blocks with MinGW; VS2013) are pointing at that opening brace of `dehexFile()` (so, not even a line of code), with each's variant of `chkstk()`. A few lines higher where `dehexFile()` is actually invoked, I even replaced `filenameList[i]` with a string constant to see if maybe it's an issue with just using the `char*` from `argv` and it still did the same thing.

What is happening here and why on Windows and not Linux?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: just because a program runs and even if it produces correct output does *not* mean that the program is itself correct. You can have an invalid memory access and, depending upon where that access is, it may or may not lead to a crash. In other words, on Linux, you were just lucky that it didn't crash (or perhaps unlucky since, if you've got a memory allocation or access error, you definitely want to know about it!). The problem might actually be in `dehexFile()`...

Comment: You've probably got an error somewhere in the code, probably in `dehexFile`.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me you have a huge array on stack in the code you're not showing.

Comment: I'll bet it has something to do with the code that uses the `LINE_SIZE` macro.

Comment: I really don't understand sometimes how people are deciding which code to show and which one to hide...

Comment: @lurker, argv[0] should never be used in the filenameList. If I missed something that excludes that, please let me know. I wasn't including dehexFile's code because the crash happens before a single line is even run, so it's not obvious to me that something inside is actually causing a crash if it's not actually run. But I suppose it could be the 2MB buffer on the stack, there is code in dehexFile that uses it. Is there a way to make error output more obvious that this might be the case?

Comment: @sorinev oops sorry my apologies. I missed the `i > 0` check you have there. It would have been clearer just to start with `i = 1` since `argv[0]` shouldn't even be considered. You could then get rid of the `if (i > 0)` check.

Comment: Lurker, I made that change, thanks. I'm so used to starting at 0 and checking all elements that I didn't even consider it. Anyhow, I use the 2MB array because I have no idea how long a line in the file will truly be. Given the context of these specific files (and how they're generated), they should never even be a quarter of that size, but I know that as soon as I make it smaller, it'll bite me.

Comment: If you use `getline()` then you do not need to be storing the data on the stack.

Comment: I ran the posted code with many different variations of command line parameters  With and without '-u' and with 0 ... 4 file names .  It does not access any 'unowned' memory and runs to completion..  The only logical conclusion is the problem is in the code that is not posted.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. My fix was to change stack variable with heap variable. Example:
Change this:

```
void dehexFile(const char* filename)
{
    HugeType obj;
...
}
```

To this:

```
void dehexFile(const char* filename)
{
    HugeType* obj = new HugeType;
...
}
```

Comment: Great, you turned a stack overrun into a heap overrun! Now it will be easier to run valgrind and find the error.